# OpenCV Circle/Contour Detection Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, webcam-capture

I am currently having issues correctly detecting circles in the image bellow (pre-processing), the output can be sporadic for the times that it will show the circles semi correctly (post-processing). The image is taken live via a webcam feed at 800*600 resolution, then passed through a bilateralFilter which helps get rid of a few false negatives (I tried a GaussianBlur but it would go extremely slow at times....).

After that it gets changed to grey then passed through the HoughCircles function to provide the output provided.

I have looked at the contours function, but i haven't found that good of documentation to figure out what each variable pertains to, if that makes sense (at least for the python functions).

I would appreciate any and all help to make this more accurate as the end goal is to take known sizes of the holes and convert that to see if the distance between the circles is off for quality control testing. (and to check if a circle is not removed ie not there).

[image: Pre-processing]

[image: Post-Processing Color]

[image: Post-Processing B&W]

CODE:

```
import cv2
import os
import math
import numpy

minRad = 50
maxRad = 75

b1 = 2
b2 = 5
b3 = 5

c1 = 5
c2 = 200
c3 = 50
c4 = 100

bw = 1

vc =cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if vc.isOpened():
    vc.set(3,800)
    vc.set(4,600)
#       vc.set(10,10)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(frame,b1,b2,b3)
#       blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(5,5),1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#frame
#       edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 200, 20, apertureSize=3)#80 120 3
    edges = gray

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,c1,c2,param1=c3,param2=c4,minRadius=minRad,maxRadius=maxRad)
    print "\n\n"
    print circles

    if circles != None:
        circles = numpy.uint16(numpy.around(circles),decimals=1)
        for cir in circles[0,:]:
            if bw == 1:
                cv2.circle(edges,(cir[0],cir[1]),cir[2],(0,255,0),2)#frame
                cv2.circle(edges,(cir[0],cir[1]),2,(0,0,255),)#frame
            else:           
                #draw outer circle
                cv2.circle(blur,(cir[0],cir[1]),cir[2],(0,255,0),2)#frame
                #draw center
                cv2.circle(blur,(cir[0],cir[1]),2,(0,0,255),)#frame
    if bw == 1:
        cv2.imwrite('/home/kasper/test/test.jpg', edges, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])   
    else:
        cv2.imwrite('/home/kasper/test/test.jpg', blur, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])
    ch = cv2.waitKey(10)

    if ch != -1:
        print "keypressed"
        print ch
        break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Circle Detection Output:

```
[[[ 652.5         507.5          62.45398331]
  [ 282.5         522.5          57.36288071]
  [ 102.5         342.5          52.84410858]
  [ 462.5         327.5          67.7089386 ]
  [ 697.5         242.5          52.52142334]
  [  82.5         547.5          52.50238037]
  [ 307.5         167.5          63.04363632]
  [  92.5         137.5          67.79749298]]]

[[[ 287.5         522.5          52.616539  ]
  [ 647.5         507.5          57.50217438]
  [ 472.5         337.5          67.7089386 ]
  [  87.5         512.5          67.78273773]
  [  82.5         292.5          67.64983368]
  [ 687.5         212.5          52.5594902 ]
  [ 302.5         162.5          67.88593292]]]
```

Comment: I managed to get a version of it working and tracking accurately now to the next step which is to convert pixel data to distance from the known value of the circle... I will be posting working code in the next 24-48 hours.

Comment: You should try template matching.

Comment: @ivan_a what if the camera got moved slightly with the template matching?

Comment: Depends, you will have to make some assumptions and restrict our system to adhere them.

Comment: Slight translation move ( non rotationary ) should not affect the performance of the system by a lot.

Comment: I just got the HoughCircle to work alot better (acurately ~+/- .09") on the Y axis by averaging the circles vertically, I am gonna add some X averaging as well the only stipulation will have to be that the camera is straight.... Though i may be able to determine straightness by detecting a line on the outside as a base.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the output has the format of (x,y,radius), where (x,y) is the center of each circle.

Comment: The output is not correct, it does not line up with the circles from preprocessing. and yes the outputs format is x,y,radius.

I am looking to be able to accurately track the circles so that i may be able to detect an offset as they progress... ie 1 set is not in line with the rest or there is too large of a gap.

Answer (score 0):

you can detect holes using this code:

```
import numpy as np 

import cv2

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

filteredContour = []

img = cv2.imread('circle.png')

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

binaryImage = np.uint8((grayImage < 100) *1)

binaryForContour = binaryImage*1

contour,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(binaryForContour,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for iteration in range (0,len(contour)):

    areaOfContour = cv2.contourArea(contour[iteration])


    if areaOfContour >= 5000:

        filteredContour.append(contour[iteration])

        cv2.drawContours(img,filteredContour, -1, (0,255,0), 2)

        plt.imshow(img)
```

The image is not clear. If the lighting is proper it will work .